# Нужно присвоить значение ключа к переменной

Tags: c#, json, классы

уважаемые программисты и сисадмины.

В этом деле я новичок.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IWebElement text = Browser.FindElement(By.TagName("pre"));
            string textt = text.Text;
            Root? r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(textt);
            string? Tradeofferid = 
            string? Assetid = 
        }
```

В переменной "textt" находится код формата json.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
namespace Test
{
 
    public class Root
    {
        public Response response { get; set; }
    }
 
    public class Response
    {
        public Trade_Offers_Received[] trade_offers_received { get; set; }
        public int next_cursor { get; set; }
    }
 
    public class Trade_Offers_Received
    {
        public string tradeofferid { get; set; }
        public int accountid_other { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public int expiration_time { get; set; }
        public int trade_offer_state { get; set; }
        public Items_To_Give[] items_to_give { get; set; }
        public bool is_our_offer { get; set; }
        public int time_created { get; set; }
        public int time_updated { get; set; }
        public bool from_real_time_trade { get; set; }
        public int escrow_end_date { get; set; }
        public int confirmation_method { get; set; }
    }
 
    public class Items_To_Give
    {
        public int appid { get; set; }
        public string contextid { get; set; }
        public string assetid { get; set; }
        public string classid { get; set; }
        public string instanceid { get; set; }
        public string amount { get; set; }
        public bool missing { get; set; }
        public string est_usd { get; set; }
    }
 
}
```

А вот сами классы. Это код формата json конвертирован в классы. Нужно к переменной "Tradeofferid" присвоить значение ключа "tradeofferid" и к переменной "Assetid" присвоить значение ключа "assetid".

Я и вправду не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Уберите знаки вопроса у класса и строк, легче разбираться станет. Эти предупреждения nullable вас только с толку сбили.

Comment: Предупреждение можно погасить еще так `Root r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(textt)!;` поставив знак восклицания после операнда. Далее можно будет обращаться к `r` как обычно.

Comment: А как вы собираетесь несколько объектов поместить в один? Вот у вас есть `Trade_Offers_Received[]`, то есть "полученные торговЫЕ запроСЫ" (множественное число), а вы хотите получить один `Tradeofferid` и один `Assetid`, вопрос как бы, какой? Если вы уверены, что там всегда один объект, то `r.response.trade_offers_received[0].tradeofferid`, если нужен конкретны, то `r.response.trade_offers_received.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.нужноеСвойство == нужноеЗначение).tradeofferid`, если надо обработать все, то проходитесь по `r.response.trade_offers_received` циклом `foreach` и работайте с каждым объектом.

Comment: И да, ужасные именования, избавляйтесь!! Вот что за `r`? А `Tradeofferid` почему с большой буквы, когда это переменная метода (должно быть `tradeOfferId `)? Сами свойства классов не обязательно должны быть такими, как в JSON, допустим это `public Trade_Offers_Received[] trade_offers_received { get; set; }`, ну приятней ведь видеть такое `public TradeOffer[] TradeOffers { get; set; }`, а чтоб работало, достаточно пометить атрибутом `[JsonProperty("trade_offers_received")]`. Ну и классы, почему `public class Trade_Offers_Received`, если класс описывает ОДИН объект (`TradeOffer` достаточно)?

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы, с вашей помощью я разобрался. А на счёт названий переменных и свойств классов, то это тестовый проект, дабы понять как это всё происходит, не хотел заморачиваться на счёт названий.

Comment: Заморачиваться надо всегда, особенно если это публикуется (как тут, на SO), иначе подобное войдет в привычку и будете считать нормой.